# Android : How to load webview with javascript in Android 4.1?

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

I am using `WebView` in my android application with these settings:

```
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewViewer);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

I am also doing some javascript editation in method onPageFinished().

When I use it in Android 5.0, everything works fine, but when I test it in Android 4.1 Console shows `error: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.example.sk`

What should I do to make it work in older Android versions too?

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Actually, 4.1 has issues on javascript. If you want to load web view on 4.1 .you can android web view by using this code

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private final String url = "Your Url";
    private WebView mWebView;
        private CustomTabsClient mClient;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (AppStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline(this)) {
                int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.noraml);
                    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    //this is for avoiding web page not found 
                            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Oops!!! Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
                } else {

                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    CustomTabsServiceConnection mConnection = new CustomTabsServiceConnection() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCustomTabsServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, CustomTabsClient customTabsClient) {
                            mClient = customTabsClient;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
                            mClient = null;
                        }
                    };

                    String packageName = "com.android.chrome";
                    CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(this, packageName, mConnection);
                }
            }
            else {
                setContentView(R.layout.error);
            }
        }
        public void loadCustomTabs(View view) {


                CustomTabsIntent.Builder mBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(getSession());

                mBuilder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.indigo_500));
                mBuilder.setCloseButtonIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp));
                mBuilder.addMenuItem("Share", setMenuItem());
                mBuilder.setStartAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                mBuilder.setExitAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                CustomTabsIntent mIntent = mBuilder.build();
                mIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));


        }

        private CustomTabsSession getSession() {
            return mClient.newSession(new CustomTabsCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onNavigationEvent(int navigationEvent, Bundle extras) {
                    super.onNavigationEvent(navigationEvent, extras);
                }
            });
        }

        private PendingIntent setMenuItem() {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject For you website");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
            return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, shareIntent, 0);
        }
}
//Custom web view
public class CustomWebView extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_web_view);
        class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals(getIntent().getStringExtra("url")))
                    return false;
                else
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Oops!!! Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }
}
```